# How can I use bot.getUserDetails in my Viber-bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, viber

I'm new in nodejs and I'm writing Viber-bot right now.
Viber-bot documentations is very bad and I really don't understand how to use some functions.
For example: I want to see some user's data, save that data on mobile device etc.
How can I use function:

```
bot.getUserDetails(userProfile)
```

I want to get name, id, phone number if it's possible and save it to some variables.

I have this code:

```
const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot;
const BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events;
const TextMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.Text;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if (!process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN) {
  console.log('Could not find bot account token key.');
  return;
}
if (!process.env.EXPOSE_URL) {
  console.log('Could not find exposing url');
  return;
}

const bot = new ViberBot({
  authToken: process.env.BOT_ACCOUNT_TOKEN,
  name: "I'm your bot",
  avatar: ""
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use("/viber/webhook", bot.middleware());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Application running on port: ${port}`);
  bot.setWebhook(`${process.env.EXPOSE_URL}/viber/webhook`).catch(error => {
    console.log('Can not set webhook on following server. Is it running?');
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

Sorry if it's stupid questions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user profile data from the response triggered in these following events.

"conversation_started"
"message_received"

```
const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot;
const BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events;

const bot = new ViberBot(logger, {
    authToken: process.env.VB_API_KEY, 
    name: "Bot Name",
    avatar: "" 
});

bot.on(BotEvents.CONVERSATION_STARTED, (response) => {

      const roomname = response.userProfile.id;
      const username = response.userProfile.name;
      const profile_pic = response.userProfile.avatar;
      const country_origin = response.userProfile.country;
      const language_origin = response.userProfile.language;

      //Do something with user data
})

bot.on(BotEvents.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, (message, response) => {
    //Same as conversation started
});
```

If you want to fetch user info specifically, you can use this endpoint describe here in viber NodeJS developer documentation. 
https://developers.viber.com/docs/all/#get_user_details

If you want to get bot info, try this endpoint.
https://developers.viber.com/docs/all/#get_account_info